# Make pywinauto run all the cmd commands before taking screenshot

Tags: pywinauto

I am writing a python script to automatically compile and run a c file in cmd(and for terminal, after it gets completed) and take the screenshot of the window after I have interacted with the C program in the cmd.

But the problem is that the screenshot gets taken before all the command line commands have run.

How do I make it wait till the exact time of finishing my work in the cmd.

```
for c in commands:
    dialog.type_keys(c, with_spaces=True, with_newlines=True)
ImageGrab.grab(box).save('window.png')
```

[Actual Screenshot Captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ4RQ.png)
[Required Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx4l0.png)

EDIT : One solution I have found is to keep taking screenshots while dialog exists, and when I finally close the command prompt the python script also exits and the final correct output is saved.
Could it be improved, also how bad is this performance wise?

Comment: Why do you need a screenshot? Maybe text output of the command is enough?

Comment: I am trying to automate my college work, a screenshot of the final window is required to be submitted.

Comment: Well, it requires ability to read console output. This is planned in pywinauto ([issue #492](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/492)), but it has low priority.